# How to figure out and find secret alien surgery?

Tags: surgeon-simulator-2013

I have finished all space surgeries,but I am still waiting to operate on the alien.
People keep talking about calling secret numbers and codes,but how exactly to figure it out and find him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On the back of the diploma** in your office you will see **first 2 digits** of 6 digit number marked and bunch of dots with some Korean letters.
The dots represent the planets and the one marked is Saturn.
The Korean translates to “the time is”.
This should help you indicate that it refers to the time it takes Saturn to make full revolution around sun which is **29** years.

---

If you were messing **around the surgeries** a lot you could have seen some hidden numbers,12 numbers to be precise,cut in pieces of two and hidden in first 6 surgeries.

They can be found in surgery number:

1. By making a hole in the blood bag you see 09
2. Inside a pills bottle you see 93
3. By stabbing yourself on green needle,you can get high and see number
   26 on the laser box.
4. Lasering the bloody note inside  the cupboard will reveal 07
5. A reflection, on the notepad shows 18
6. On the road(when ambulance doors are opened)you can see number 50

This puts together Trishas new phone number 099326071850.
Call it and new note will appear on your desk.
If you take a pen and scribble over it you will reveal that **2 digits in the middle** are **61**.

---

**On front of your diploma** in your office read the name of the university,which is *Barnardshire*.
If you google that it will lead you to the [barnardshire general hospital](http://barnardshire-general.co.uk/contacts.html) where under "contact us" you will find the number of the surgery team  80554194999.

If you call that number on your office phone a new VHS Tape will appear on your desk marked with *GGN4X*.
If you put it in your VHS player  you will see that it shows **last 2 digits** of 6 digit number and that they are in your pocket.

It refers to your real mobile phone.If you are among the lucky ones(based on your country and phone number) you can call your phone number (with country code prefix) in-game and you could **receive an actual phone call !**(how awesome is that),which will be a womans voice followed by a binary code.Translated it will mean 9*5 which is **45**.

---

Now you have all 6 digits of the secret code,in the last space surgery enter **296145** on the keypad near the hatch,and you will see that something starts to happen (quickly grab and hold the radio if you want another achievement).

New VHS tape will appear on your desk with some weird symbols on it,put it in the VHS player and look on the TV screen,you will see numbers **4,9,4 and 8** remember them since you will have to enter them to start the alien surgery that will start soon.

If you want to read chronologically how people figured this out look [here](http://jmad.blog.com/).

Or for a video guide [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uva_NlsnnOs).